# LocalReport hangs sometimes on render

Tags: c#, rdlc

When generating a RDLC report in  a C#/WPF application, *sometimes* it hangs on render (call of `render` method doesn't return).

The report data comes from a C# object (which is filled in advance with data from a PostgreSQL database) so this issue is not SQL related.

I wonder:

1. How can I find out the reason?
2. Is there any way to enable the user to kill the report generation when it hangs?

Embedding the report generation in a `using` block (as seen in [ReportViewer rendering hangs server after some executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403053/reportviewer-rendering-hangs-server-after-some-executions)) didn't solve the problem.

```
using (LocalReport report = new LocalReport())
{
    report.ReportPath = @"C:\Path\To\MyReport.rdlc";

    // Get the report data from db and fill it into MyReportData object.
    MyReportData data = CreateReportData();

    ReportDataSource headerDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
    headerDataSource.Name = "HeaderDataSet";
    headerDataSource.Value = data.Header;
    report.DataSources.Add(headerDataSource);

    // Add more data sources ...

    // No report parameters are being used

    report.Refresh();

    pdfData = report.Render("PDF"); // here it hangs sometimes
}
```

As said above, the `render`-call hangs sometimes. After killing the application and generating exactly the same report again it works.

Comment: Does the report contain any rows when it fails?  How many rows does query contain when it fails?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by rows. The report contains some tables, all together the report is about 10 pages long.

Comment: The number of rows in the results of a query.  What version of SQL Server are you using?  How large is the database?  Issue could have to do with the database being fragmented especially if you are using SQL Server Express.

Comment: I'm not using SQL Server, I'm using PostgreSQL. The report data doesn't come directly from a SQL Resultset but from a C# object. So my issue is not related to the number of rows.

Comment: Any query to any database always returns row of data!!!